# using open file dialog box on a windows form

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I wrote a program which reads a csv file, makes some changes and writes to a new csv file.

I want the user to be able to select the csv file to be read from their directory using an open file dialog box on a windows form.

So far I have been able to write some of the code so that the user can look for the file but I am not sure on how to link the file the user has chosen to the steamreader.

This is the code to read and write the csv file

```
try 
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("X:/PublishedSoftware/Data/NEWPYAEGON1PENSION.csv"))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(""))
        {
```

This is the code for the open file dialog box

```
private void btnFindAegonFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "csv files(*.csv)|*.csv|All files(*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FileName = "Browse for the AEGON file.";

    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    txtFindAegonFile.Text = this.openFileDialog1.FileName;
```

Comment: I thought that was the only thing you could put the file path in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working I used:

```
string readfilename = txtFindAegonFile.Text;

try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(readfilename))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("X:/PublishedSoftware/Data/NEWPYAEGON1PENSION.csv"))
}
```

Comment: The file name will be different every week

Comment: If you use a textbox then the user can see the chosen directory though

Answer (score 3):

If you have the file name:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string fileName = this.openFileDialog1.FileName;

    ...
}
```

You can read the contents using the stream reader (in the place of `...`):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
```

Or read the contents directly:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

Comment: Good answer. +1 for mentioning `File.ReadAllText` ... this and `WriteAllText` saves you the whole `Stream` and `using` stuff ...

Comment: @Hinek: Thanks. Indeed it is the way to go in most scenarios. `StreamReader` might get useful with large files, or files where you only want to read the first X characters.

Comment: This wont work because I am using the streamReader as I want to read in one line at a time and it has to be at the top of the program

Comment: @user3734454: I don't quite understand your comment. You can use the `using ...` from my answer, right?

Comment: yes but my streamreader is in a different method from the open file dialog method

Comment: Then assign a local variable and save the path there.

Comment: @user3734454: Need more help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to complete the FileOpen Dialog code snippet by passing the file path to StreamWriter, like:

```
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName));
  // ... open the file w/StreaWriter
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `openFileDialog1`'s [`FileOK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.fileok%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to know when the user has selected a valid file. You can then recive the file path from `openFileDialog1.FileName`.

Comment: How do I use it to know when the user has selected a valid file?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.fileok(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of how to go from a file name to a StreamReader:

```
var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
{
...
}
```